# Alternative to Taylor's formula

Tags: calculus

[image]

Given these inequalities and the fact that $2<e<3$ and that $g(x)=e^x$ is increasing, I am first to reason why A1 and A2 is true.

For A1, I subsituted $e^{e^x}$ with $e^u$ and showed that we get the same inequality when substitutig back.

For A2 I used the facts given, which means that $g(x_1)<g(x_2)$ when $x_1<x_2$ for $x_1,x_2 € I$, and that $g'(x)>0$ for all $x$. Then I put $x=1$ such that $e^x € (2,3)= I$. If wee remove the coefficients $e^{Sx}$ and $3^3$, the last two parts of the inequality are identical. Then, for $n=e$ we get:

$$\begin{align}
&e^{e^e}+e^x+\frac{e^{2x}}{2}+\frac{e^{3x}}{6}+...+\frac{e^{ex}}{e!}+e^{Sx}\frac{e^{(e+1)x}}{(e+1)!}
\end{align}$$
For an $S€(0,e^x)$

And for $(0<x<1)$ we have $1<e^{Sx}<e^x<e^{e^1}<3^3$, and we see that $1<e^{Sx}<3^3$, hence we see that the inequality holds.

I feel like I have answered this part of the assignment correct, but if I have made a mistake I would appreciate being corrected and shown the right way.

But my question is for part B and C: I am to find an $n$ (I assume using brute force because we are trying to use an alternative method than using Taylor's formula) such that
$$\begin{align}
&\frac{27}{2}*\frac{e^{n+1}-1}{(n+1)(n+1)!}< 0.05
\end{align}$$
by using the info gathered from A1 and A2 to calculate $\int_0^1e^{e^x}dx$ with an error less than $0.05$.
My thought here is to bruteforce to find the $n$ and then substitute $e^{e^x}$with what I found in A (i.e. the Taylor Polynomial) and then calculate the integral and find an error $< 0.05$ to this with the belonging $n$. But how do I do this in practice?

Comment: $\frac{27}{2}*\frac{e^{n+1}-1}{(n+1)(n+1)!}< 0.05$ for $n\ge 9$ (brute force). Integral is $6.31656$, for reference.

Comment: Could you show how you calculated this answer?

Comment: It's impossible to solve the inequality with usual algebraic tools, so I made a table of values and foud out that the LHS is less than $0.05$ for $n=9$ $$
\begin{array}{r|l} n & R(n)\\ \hline\\
 1 & 21.56 \\
 2 & 14.31 \\
 3 & 7.537 \\
 4 & 3.317 \\
 5 & 1.258 \\
 6 & 0.4192 \\
 7 & 0.1247 \\
 8 & 0.03349 \\
 9 & 0.008194 \\
 10 & 0.001841 \\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Okay, I think I get it now. Thank you!

Comment: Why not use $n\ge8$?

Comment: Because I am sleeping and didn't see that 0.033 is less than 0.05, LOL!